# some doubts related to REST API

Tags: api, soap, rest

1. Can we say Like `Rest API` we have `SOAP`, `XML RPC`, `JSON RPC`, `GRAPH QL` I mean `Rest` is just a type of API?
2. Is `Rest` is just a mechanism to share data between applications by using `HTTP` methods?
3. REST can share data between applications only with `HTTP` there is no alternative?
4. What is the relation between `REST` & `CRUD` exactly? we are saying `HTTP: POST` is `CRUD: CREATE` my question is `HTTP: POST` will just post the data to server and it's business logic's headache to `CREATE A NEW RESOURCE` in the `server side` but how we all are saying `HTTP: POST` is nothing but `CRUD: CREATE` here `HTTP: POST` is just helping to share the data only right then how it is related to `CRUD: CREATE`? If that is the case `we can create a new resource with HTTP: GET by writing business logic right` then why so many sites are saying `REST is a mechanism to do CRUD operations`... But it should be `REST is a mechanism to help in Sharing the data between applications right`?!!! (I have doubt similarly with HTTP: DELETE, GET, PUT aswell)
5. Last but not least... what exactly `Representational state transfer` mean? could you please answer this with a very low level general answer instead of definition.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yeaahhh…? 3. I guess you could do REST over other protocols, but that's not how it's typically defined. 4. Wut? Please trim that down a bit. 5. How much have you researched into this already and what don't you understand? The answer to this could be very terse or very long, depending on what exactly you expect as an answer.

Comment: Hey @deceze Thanks for your reply. forgot about point 5. could you please check point 4... Yes, It's little bit big but that is what my doubt is.. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Can we say Like Rest API we have SOAP, XML RPC, JSON RPC, GRAPH QL I mean Rest is just a type of API?

REST stands for representation state transfer and is just an architectural style, not a technology or protocol. According to Robert C. "Uncle Bob" Martin an [architecture is about intent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_TH-Y78tt4&t=860s) and the intention behind REST is the decoupling of servers and clients in a distributed system.

REST basically just defines a set of constraints that when followed correctly allow servers to change at any time without breaking clients as clients will just depend on the data given by the server and not on any external data or documentation. REST can be regarded as Web surfing for applications. The main premise should always be that a server teaches a client on how certain things can be achieved.

On the Web a server can i.e. teach a client on the supported properties of a resource through the help of [HTML forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html). Not only does a client learn that way what a server expects as input, it also learns what HTTP operation should be used to send the data to the server, the endpoint URI to send the request to as well as, usually implicitly given, also the media type to convert the input to, which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` usually by default, which transforms an input like the HTML example below for first and lastname to something like this:

```
fName=Roman&lName=Vottner
```

> 2. Is Rest is just a mechanism to share data between applications by using HTTP methods?

REST itself is protocol agnostic meaning that it is not tide to HTTP itself and could just work on other transport protocols as well. Though the common perception many developers have is that it is based on HTTP. After all, as Jim Webber put it, [HTTP is just a transport layer whose domain is the transfer of files or data over the Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s). All HTTP does is to send one document from one machine to the next and any business rules we conclude from sending/receiving a request are just a side effect of the actual document management. It is therefore always better to think of a request as a whole document and the HTTP operation define how the document should be stored on the current machine, especially when such a document is already available, instead of thinking of a service method invocations. The latter one is a typical RPC view.

> 3. REST can share data between applications only with HTTP there is no alternative?

HTTP is just a transport layer used in a REST architecture. The architecture cares more on the interaction model between client and servers than on the technical nuances of HTTP. As REST itself is transport protocol agnostic it could be used with other, maybe proprietary protocols as well.

> 4. What is the relation between REST & CRUD exactly? we are saying HTTP: POST is CRUD: CREATE my question is HTTP: POST will just post the data to server and it's business logic's headache to CREATE A NEW RESOURCE in the server side but how we all are saying HTTP: POST is nothing but CRUD: CREATE here HTTP: POST is just helping to share the data only right then how it is related to CRUD: CREATE? If that is the case we can create a new resource with HTTP: GET by writing business logic right then why so many sites are saying REST is a mechanism to do CRUD operations... But it should be REST is a mechanism to help in Sharing the data between applications right?!!! (I have doubt similarly with HTTP: DELETE, GET, PUT aswell)

[Fielding's thesis on the REST architecture style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) does not contain the term CRUD at all. The term REST nowadays is heavily misused as people probably didn't bother to actually read the thesis, which admittingly is a bit abstract, and just follow what some people [thought may be REST but was actually RPC](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven). Nowadays, if a typical stakeholder talks about REST they usually think of a JSON-based HTTP CRUD-API whose supported endpoints are defined in some Web documentation (Swagger, OpenAPI, ...) and where the HTTP operations for `POST` (= Create), `GET` (= Read), `PUT` (= Update), `Delete` (= Delete) are supported by default. However, this is unfortunately far from the truth. Though people are just to accustomed with their (wrong) definition and don't see or don't care about the actual problem in their misusage. They don't care about a long-lasting service as in 2-5 years the next-gen technology is here that allows to reduce the number of lines of codes even more and if a new "version" of a service is needed, this usually goes hand in hand with a technology switch also, to justify the "cost of change" somehow.

> 5. Last but not least... what exactly Representational state transfer mean? could you please answer this with a very low level general answer instead of definition.

Probably the easiest way to grasp how the interaction in a REST architecture should be is by analyzing typical interaction on the Web, the big cousin of REST. You, as a user, usually start by opening your browser (= client) and typing in some URL in the search bar. Next a Web page is rendered on your screen. Behind the curtain a couple of things happened. Besides the whole connection management and any eventual TLS handshake your browser sent at least one `GET` request to the target server. On sending the GET request, the client included information on his capabilities, i.e. through the `Accept` HTTP header. This header is used on the server side to decide which representation format to generate and send to the user. On the Web this might be something like `text/html` or `application/xhtml+xml` or if some report is generated might be something like `application/pdf` or `application/vnd.ms-excel` or the like, depending which representation format fit the data best.

The representation format itself is now a concrete instance of a document following a certain media type specification. I.e. the [HTML forms specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html) defines the supported elements within a `<form>...</form>` tag pair as well as describes the semantics of each of the elements. The concrete instance may now define a form as such:

```html
 <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

which should only use elements and attributes defined within the specification else a receiver of that document might not be able to process it correctly.

This process of telling the server which document types a client supports and allowing the server to chose a fitting representation is called *content type negotiation* and allows the exchange of [arbitrary, type-less documents](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). Of course, both parties need to support and understand at least one common media type to be able to interact with each other. This is similar to a Frenchmen who does not understand a word of Chinese and a Chinese one that does not understand any word of French who need to communicate (for whatever reason), if both speak English they will be able to communicate.

There are loads of [different media types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) already available that all server different purposes. Depending on your needs an all-purpose one, such as `text/html`, might be sufficient, others such as `application/json` or even `application/hal+json` might though lack support for certain needed elements. Existing media types might not support needed elements. In such a case extending such media types and registering those is probably easier than creating a whole media type from scratch.

REST assumes that a resource (i.e. a remote document) contains some internal data, its state. This state can be represented in many different ways. Think of some monthly sails figures. You might ship the data either in a HTML table, as CSV data, as Excel file, as PDF or yet a different representation format. Regardless of the chosen media type to marshal the data in, the actual data at least should express the same. Instead of questioning which media type you want to support, you should better ask how many different ones you want to support as this just increases the likelihood that other clients may interact with your server also.

---

edit:

> I got all the points except 4th point... Could you please elaborate a bit.. So is it just a mechanism that helps in sharing the data between applications by using HTTP methods? we can say like that?

CRUD is a typical term in the context of persistence, especially with databases. REST or more formally the REST architecture itself treats persistence as internal detail. A typical user usually does not care whether some data is persisted into a DB, a local file system or is kept just in memory. All s/he cares is that the server can process it or for storage services also return the same data that was sent to the server.

In regards to the mapping of CRUD to the HTTP operations, if you take a look at HTML you might see that it only supports `POST` and `GET` operations. So anything related to `C`, `U` or `D` are performed with `POST` which is defined to [*process the enclosed representation according to the resource's own semantic*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3). With `POST` you are basically allowed to do anything, even retrieving data if you like.

However, HTTP defines [certain properties](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2) for the respective operations:

- safe
- idempotent
- cacheable

The first property is a promise to clients that a well-behaved server should not alter the state of a resource upon requesting. The second one is a promise in regards to automatic retry attempts caused by i.e. temporary connection issues. And the latter one allows clients to store responses locally and reuse these instead of requesting the same resource again, if the cached content is "fresh-enough".

`GET` and `HEAD` are both safe, idempotent and cacheable, meaning that a client can request resources with such an operation without being hold accountable for any eventual changes. Think of a Web spider that is invoking arbitrary URIs all the time to learn new pages over time. If a `GET` request on a URI would trigger an order of a Pizza or the like, it is basically the server's fault and not the clients one if a crawler would order Pizzas every time such URIs are called.

`PUT` and `DELETE` are only idempotent, which basically allows a client to automatically resend a request in case of a network issue as the outcome of the operation leads to the same result regardless whether the request was processed once or multiple times in a row. Note that this property does not consider changes done by other clients to that resource between a resend. Such data would of course be overwritten.

The remaining operations (POST, PATCH, CONNECT, TRACE) are neither of these.

While technically it is sufficient to only use `POST` for each request, the above mentioned properties should trigger an inner intention to use them, when appropriate. However, as before mentioned, not the client should chose which operation to perform but the server should tell a client which HTTP operation it should use.

In regards to `POST` vs. `PUT`, both operations should behave similar on creating a resource. Both need to add a `Location` header within the response that teaches a client about the location of the new resource. `PUT` however, in contrast to `POST`, replaces the current representation of the requested resource with the one provided in the request body. So it already targets the respective resource while for a `POST` request the server defines where the resource is created. It is allowed to perform certain sanity checks and also to transform the representation to fit the representation format of the current one. It is also allowed to have side effects, i.e. think of Git where a commit creates a new entry on top of the current branch and moves the HEAD to the new commit.

`PUT` is probably considered as update operation as the replacement of the document more or less has the effect of an update. If no representation was yet available this just has the effect of the creation (including the location header). In the past, unfortunately, many developers used PUT incorrectly by performing a partial update instead of really replacing the whole document. While [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) states that a partial update could be achieved by overlapping resources (i.e. share parts of the same data in multiple resources), the usage of PATCH, which also is used incorrectly most of the time, may be better from a performance standpoint on larger resources.

Due to `POST`s definition, one can do anything with it, though historically a document upload in HTML was triggered through this operation that is basically a resource creation on the server side. That POST is used for many other things as well though is not that important for that CRUD paradigm.

In regards to your concerns about the right terminology, most people, according to my experience, simply do not care. They just want to get the job done ASAP and move on. As roughly 90% of the users seem to understand a pretty similar concept when talking about REST (even though this view is flawed) which usually resolves around JSON, HTTP, CRUD, Swagger/OpenAPI, ... they usually only look for quick-win-solutions and more or less agreement on their thought process.

As HTTP (0.9-1.1) is a plain text protocol sending a GET request is not much different from a POST or PUT request, so technically you can create resources with GET request or support payloads on GET requests (semantics of the payload is undefined according to the spec). That's why I mentioned well-behaved client/servers above. In such a case, however, due to the safe property of `GET`, if you as a server maintainer violate the HTTP protocol you are the one to blame in case something "unexpected" is happening (crawler is ordering 500 Pizzas).

Comment: Hey @roman-vottner Thanks a lot for your answer. I got all the points except 4th point... Could you please elaborate a bit.. So is it just a mechanism that helps in sharing the data between applications by using HTTP methods? we can say like that?